# geo4js - commands not found when installing

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to install geo4js, but it's saying that two commands are not found:

Noahs-iMac:~ noahgordon18$ sudo -s
bash-3.2# wget -O - http://debian.neo4j.org/neotechnology.gpg.key | apt-key add -
bash: apt-key: command not found
bash: wget: command not found
bash-3.2#

Any ideas?

Comment: I was able to install the wget command, but now I'm getting: Cannot write to `-' (Broken pipe).

Answer (score 0):

For OSX (which you are on), there is no `wget` installed per default. Please try either Debian for this installation, or for OSX, install https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew and do

```
brew install neo4j
```